# Handle gorm unique constraint is a consistent way

Tags: go-gorm

How can I handle unique constraints errors in gorm in a non hackish way? The goal is to support different database, but what I have seen so far is that this error is only returned as a database specific error. In my dev environment when using sqlite I get:

```
Code = sqlite.ErrNo 19
ExtendedCode = sqlite.ErrNoExtendedCode = 2067
```

Obviously checking this manually in an error facade is not practical and will be different for any other database. Also I do not want to check it before in my code since then the code must have knowledge of all data models and their constraints. This sounds bad.
How can this be handled?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error `gorm.ErrDuplicatedKey` in a newer release. If gorm is configured with:

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger:         zapLogger,
        TranslateError: true,
    })
```

also this error is translated.